# How to Validate the value of a form in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to validate the value of a form (a checkbox actually) in a model, but am having a lot of trouble finding what to pass validates:

```
  validates :agreement, :agreement => true
```

I've gotten other things to work like:

```
  validates :password, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 6, :maximum => 25}, :confirmation => true
```

My view looks like this:

```
        <% form_for :signup_form, :url => {:controller => "user", :action => "post_signup"} do |f| %>
```

...
            
              
                <%= f.check_box( :agreement ) %> I agree to the <%= link_to("Terms of Service", :controller=> "about", :action => "terms") %> and <%= link_to("Privacy Policy", :controller=> "about", :action => "privacy") %>
              
...

Which then goes to my controller:

```
    agreement = params[:signup_form][:agreement]

new_user = User.create(:login_name => login_name, :first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name, :email => email, :password => password, :agreement => agreement, :created_at => DateTime.now())
```

And then my model.

Thanks for any help you can offer in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to display your errors on the page, and ensure your validation is working at all. I would re-implement your validation as:

```
 # app/models/user.rb
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :agreement do |ag|
     ag.errors.add "Must agree to the terms" unless self.agreement
   end

 end
```

see http://asciicasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3 for a comprehensive treatment, including a nice way to display the errors.

Comment: thanks!  displaying errors in a nice way was also something I've been trying to do.  Before I had just checked for obviously incorrect input in my controller and set a flash variable to what I wanted to display:       flash[:signup_error] = "Incomplete form found.  Please try again"
      redirect_to(:controller => "user", :action => "signup")

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize you could validate this way. I used the validate :method_name

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [:acceptance => true](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/AcceptanceValidator.html) or [validates_acceptance_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_acceptance_of)